# TableTools path doesn't work

Tags: datatable, tabletools

I try to run TableTools but I have a problem.

Copy, CSV, Excel and PDF not work but print is ok.

I put into the sSwfPath : CDN 2.2.2

I have an console error :GET http://localhost/development/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf 404 (Not Found)

```
var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table, {
   "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": 
        {
             "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
             "aButtons": [
             {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sButtonText": '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                    "sPdfMessage": "Your custom message would go here."
                },
                 {
                    "sExtends": "xls",
                    "sButtonText": '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>'
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "print",
                    "sButtonText": '<i class="fa fa-print"></i>'
                }

             ]
           }
} );

$( tt.fnContainer()).insertAfter('.header-link');
```

I don't understand my error.

Thanks

Comment: `http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf` is a valid path ... if you have change to that from using  `http://localhost/development/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf` then it probably is a cache issue.

Comment: I clear my cache and nothing. Maybe the path of my project (`http://localhost/development/myproject/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf`) and my error (`http://localhost/development/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf`)

Comment: Always use the CDN, ie http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf there is like 200 questions on SO by people who cannot get tabletools to work because they use a wrong path to the .swf.